# $\lim_{\rho\to0}\int_{\gamma_{\rho}}g(z)e^{iz}dz=-\pi i Res(f,a)$ with a pole $a\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

Let $U$ be an open neighbourhood of $\overline{\mathbb{H}}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\Im(z)\ge0\}$ and $g:U\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ meromorphic with a finite number of poles in $\mathbb{H}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\Im(z)>0\}$ and one pole $a\in\mathbb{R}$ with order one. Assume that $\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty} g(z)=0$ and put $f(z)=g(z)e^{iz}$.

I want to show:

> $$\lim_{\rho\to0}\int_{\gamma_{\rho}}f(z)dz=-\pi i Res(f,a) ,$$ where $\gamma_{\rho}:[0,\pi]\to \mathbb{C}, \gamma_{\rho}(t)=a+\rho e^{i(\pi-t)}$.

If we have this result: How does this help to show $$\int_{-\infty}^{a}f(x)dx+\int_a^{\infty}f(x)dx=\pi iRes(f,a)+2\pi i \sum_{z\in\mathbb{H}}Res(f,z)?$$

It would be great if somebody has an indea how we can apply the Residue theorem.

Comment: if you shrink your contour of integration to small enough circle, only the singularity at $a$ will be contained and therefor yields the only contribution to the integral. Because you encircle it half it will only add half of the residue and the above result follows (the minus sign comes from the fact that u encircle the point $a$ clockwise)

Comment: Shrinking was the hint I needed! Thank you. I have added another question (see my edit), refering to the first one. Do you have an indea?

Comment: you have calculated the contribution from the real axis singulartiy now add the other singularties to calculate the integral over the real line (if some decay properties at $|z|\rightarrow \infty$ are fulfilled). This is just a version of the residue theorem